# Proxy for SWT browser

Tags: java, browser, proxy, swt

I am writing an SWT application, and I need to proxy http requests from SWT browser to the outside world (in order to fiddle with data that comes back).

The first thing I thought of was using a web proxy. [Boom](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserproxy).

> All Browser instances automatically use Windows' or OS X's
>   global proxy settings.

When googling for alternatives I found [this thread](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=82295). They have some Mozilla-specific workarounds that are using `nsIServiceManager` dark magic, and I tend to think there have to be much more sane (and cross-browser) way to do that.

Also, I don‘t need a full-fledged web proxy. Just about any technique to intercept http request and change its response would be just fine. (Without an overkill of setting up system-wide proxy, that is.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you detail your usecase a bit further? What do you need to change?

Comment: @FabianZeindl I need to be able to mangle data that SWT browser sends to and receives from the network.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to configure the proxy via Java code?

```
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyHost", "someProxyURL");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPort", "someProxyPort");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyUser", "someUserName");
System.getProperties().put("http.proxyPassword", "somePassword");
```

This can be configured in your app startup class